# Magento 2 installing 2 instance of same module

Tags: magento2.2, braintree

I want to use 2 instance of Braintree module at different setting. Anyway by which it can be achieved? Or any way to configure it with 2 settings?

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: I just want to install another instance of Braintree payment gateway

Answer (score 0):

It is my experience that you can't associate more than one set of Braintree API keys with a single Magento store. You would need to create two Magento stores and associate each set of API keys with one store.

Comment: You might be able to by editing the code where it grabs the current API keys, but at the end of the day the most straightforward and supported way is like you said, to create multiple store views

Comment: yeah @zack6849- totally plausible in theory. But you'll probably run into issues getting support _and_ you run the risk of edge cases where you're charging customers from the wrong account, increasing your risk for chargebacks.